# Program seems to ignore first user input

Tags: python

I'm having trouble having the program not ignore the first user input value. I want to make the program take that value and either add it to the other even values if its even, or odd values if it is odd. Also, I'm trying to get the program to count up how many even numbers and odd numbers were input, but again the first number is ignored.

```
# list of all the variables used in the program
interger_str = input("Input an interger (0 terminates): ")
interger_int = int(interger_str)
odd_count = 0
even_count = 0
even_sum = 0
odd_sum = 0

while (interger_int > 0 or interger_int < 0):
    interger_str = input("Input an interger (0 terminates): ")
    interger_int = int(interger_str)

    if (interger_int < 0):
        interger_int == 0
        interger_str = input("Input an interger (0 terminates): ")
        interger_int = int(interger_str)

# count the number of even intergers entered
    if (interger_int % 2 == 0):
        even_count
        even_count += 1
        even_sum += interger_int

# count the number of odd intergers entered
    if (interger_int % 2 == 1):
        odd_count
        odd_count = odd_count + 1
        odd_sum = odd_sum + interger_int
else:

    print("\nCount of odd numbers: ", odd_count)
    print("Count of even numbers: ", even_count)
    print("Sum of odd numbers: ", odd_sum)
    print("Sum of even numbers: ", even_sum)
```

Thanks in advance!

Example output:
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kd39H.png)

*Zero is included as even

Comment: Look at when you are asking the user to input values.  Run through the loop in your head.  Do you use the value you collect outside of the loop before collecting another value?

Comment: `interger_int == 0` probably doesn't do what you think it does, why do you get a second input before checking if it's even or odd

Comment: your `if...else` is not properly indented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are replacing your first value in while loop.

Below code define default value, and get input in while loop.

```
# list of all the variables used in the program
interger_int = 1
odd_count = 0
even_count = 0
even_sum = 0
odd_sum = 0

while (interger_int > 0 or interger_int < 0):
    interger_str = input("Input an interger (0 terminates): ")
    interger_int = int(interger_str)

    if (interger_int < 0):
        continue

# count the number of even intergers entered
    if (interger_int % 2 == 0):
        even_count
        even_count += 1
        even_sum += interger_int

# count the number of odd intergers entered
    elif (interger_int % 2 == 1):
        odd_count
        odd_count = odd_count + 1
        odd_sum = odd_sum + interger_int
    else:
        break

print("\nCount of odd numbers: ", odd_count)
print("Count of even numbers: ", even_count)
print("Sum of odd numbers: ", odd_sum)
print("Sum of even numbers: ", even_sum)
```